# What is wrong from the performance standpoint?

Tags: c

I just wrote a simple code to display time in hh:mm:ss format. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  time_t curtime;
  int h, m, s, ps;
  struct tm *x = localtime(&curtime);

  time(&curtime);
  ps = (*x).tm_sec;
  while(1)
    {
      time(&curtime);
      x = localtime(&curtime);
      h = (*x).tm_hour;
      m = (*x).tm_min;
      s = (*x).tm_sec;
      if(s != ps)
        {
          ps = s;
          printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s);
        }
    }
  return(0);
}
```

The code compiles and runs as expected. However the cpu usage seems to go really high. When I use 'top' to see cpu usage, it shows cpu% as 96-100% (and I can hear the computer fan loud). How can I improve the code from a performance angle keeping the code simple and short?

Comment: See [Is it okay to ask code optimization question help?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286559/1079354) to see what it is you're missing.  Right now, there's nothing that I can see that would make malperformance apparent (except that wonderful infinite loop).

Comment: Are you exiting `while(1)`?

Comment: The while is not what I am focusing on. Okay I can add some condition say "if (ps == 50) break". Will that make it a better code? It's not the while loop I am talking about. The cpu usage will still be high.

Comment: So your asking why is `while(1) {doStuff();}` slow?

Comment: @John3136 It's not slow. It's exactly as it expected in showing result. I am concerned about cpu usage. I want to reduce that.

Comment: @anupamb You can't do that within your program without it becoming very complex very quickly. Let the OS scheduler do its thing, and don't run an infinite loop if you don't want your CPU pegged. You could put your program to sleep periodically within the infinite loop, but while it's executing and *not* asleep, there's no easy way to tell the CPU to not execute it as fast as it can. That's what the system is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Think in the morning. Act in the noon. Eat in the evening. `sleep()` in the night.

Comment: @skrrgwasme OK Thanks.

Comment: Please learn to use the `x->tm_min` etc notation.  The `(*x).tm_min` notation looks most peculiar in C code — it marks you as a novice programmer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :). I am.

Comment: You could use a subsecond timer to sleep most of the time.  As it stands, you're rattling around the loop mostly not printing because the current second hasn't changed. On Linux, you could use [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html): `struct timespec ts = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 100000000 }; nanosleep(&ts, 0);` to sleep for 1/10 second at a time. That will radically reduce the workload on the system. If you don't have `nanosleep()`, you might have `usleep()` — micro-sleep.  At a pinch, you could use `sleep(1);` — or `Sleep(1000);` on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! Yes that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that your loop hardly contain anything to be waited on (the only thing is the `printf`s, but I assume that you redirect that or that `printf` for some other reason completes quickly). This means that the program always is eligible to run.

All other programs that run on your computer on the other hand often wait for something: user input, network messages or whatever. That means that they are not eligible to run most of the time.

What the operating system does then is because your program has work to do, but no other process has (currently) it will schedule your program to run most of the time (96-100%). Consequently it will consume that much CPU.

This is normally not a bad thing. If your program has work to do it should be given the opportunity to do so if it's the only program that has. It's not really about performance - or put in another way, it's about performance it is that the OS will give your program the opportunity to finish as fast as possible (although it has no idea that it will not finish at all in this case).

One thing one often does with these kind of processes (ie those that are CPU bound) is to lower their priority. This may seem counterintuitive at first, but in effect it will tell the OS to assign to that process all processing power that's not used for anything else, it would mean that there will be processing power available whenever some other program has to process a mouse click, or keyboard input (which means that you wouldn't notice that much that there's a CPU heavy computation going on). Some OSes tries to do this automatically (Linux for example will give precedence to processes that wait a lot).

Comment: Wow. This is a surprisingly excellent answer to what I thought was a poorly scoped and minimally useful question. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, since you have an infinite loop, your program will use all processor power to execute itself as fast as possible. Most simple c programs terminate within seconds, so this isn't a problem. Yours however, doesn't.

To at least curb the CPU usage heavily, you can leave a `sleep()` instruction after every iteration of the loop, to give the system time to do other things in between.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    while(1) {
        printf("Aha");
        sleep(1);     // 1s sleep
        // Windows:
        // ::Sleep(500); // 500ms
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sleep(500)` waits for 500 *seconds*.

Comment: @alk Wait.... nvm you're right. I had a different language in mind. I corrected it.

Comment: On Windows, `Sleep(500)` sleeps for half a second (500 milliseconds).  Note the capital S.

Comment: `sleep(1)` sleeps for one second + the time it takes to do context switch, do something completely unrelated for a while and then come back. Linux is not a RTOS. Given that the OP seems to require second accuracy, `sleep(1)` is too crude.

Comment: @Lundin Thats why I also posted the Sleep() alternative after Jonathan's comment in an edit.